# Why do fields seem to be a prerequisite for calculus?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, field-theory

I was in my Complex Analysis class, and the professor said that we should look for a field, rather than a group, to do calculus over. Why is this the case? I understand that we gain another operation with a field, but if it's just a matter of gaining another operation, why not use some object with three operations. (I've never learned of one.)

So why do we seem to want fields, like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ for performing calculus over? Is there something about them that makes analysis *work*, or are they simply a richer subject of study? If the latter, why not include more operations?

Comment: I suppose one reason is that the definition of a derivative uses both addition and division.

Comment: An example of an object with three operations: an algebra over a ring, which has vector addition, a vector multiplication, and scalar multiplication.

Comment: @Hayden I suppose I have seen that then.

Comment: Completeless of the extension $\mathbb R$ of $\mathbb Q$ and $\mathbb Z$, and the fact that every polynomial in $\mathbb R [x]$ factors completely with roots in $\mathbb C$; $\mathbb C$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @TomCruise I believe you mean $\mathbb{C}$ rather than $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @user54092 I suppose so. More generally for analysis then, is multiplication required? It seems to me we talk a lot about sequences in analysis, for which multiplication doesn't seem necessary. It shows up in distances, but wouldn't it be possible to define distance without multiplication? It seems like a very *additive* thing.

Comment: What is an algebraic closure?

Comment: @Anthony The definition of a metric space and a metric by extension does not explicitly require anything to do with multiplication, though common examples use it (i.e. Euclidean metric).

Comment: @Anthony The algebraic closure of a field $\mathbb{F}$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{F}$ in which every polynomial splits completely.

Comment: @Hayden So is there a good example of a metric space we do calculus over that doesn't have multiplication? Or does *calculus* require multiplication.

Comment: @Anthony none that I know of.  In order to talk about differentiation, multiplication is a must (since division is just a special case of division).  Even when defining the Riemann integral, multiplication is required.

Comment: I see. I suppose I'm okay with accepting you need multiplication for defining a derivative- is there really no way to define an integral using just summations?

Comment: @Anthony For integration - you need to multiply the measure of each interval in the partition by the estimated height at that point, since we are trying to estimate the area under the curve. Since multiplication is the basic operation for finding area, I would think that it could not be avoided unless you are willing to work in a discrete setting where multiplication is just repeated addition. That's just my guess though.

Comment: Don't we need some sort of topological structure too? Unless you work in finite domain or codomain, you are going to encounter function that take on an infinite number of values. Just a field is not enough. Though there is no requirement that the topological structure be compatible with the field structure.

Comment: Usually analysis is done over a complete field (e.g. $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ or the $p$-adics). Yet, to do integration you can construct a Haar measure (measure invariant by tanslations) just over a locally compact group. Indeed, over complete fields you have *two* Haar measures: the additive and the multiplicative ones

Comment: @Gina I'm afraid I don't follow.